# Check HTTP cookie value with nginx using map directive

Tags: nginx, cookies, http-cookie

I need to perform a redirect depending on the client's IP and the value that has been set  in the cookie by WPML Wordpress plugin.

I prefer to use the map directive for this purpose.
Excerpt of *nginx.conf*

```
 geoip_country /usr/local/share/GeoIP/maxmind_countries.dat;
 geoip_city   /usr/local/share/GeoIP/maxmind_cities.dat;


map $host:$geoip_country_code:$cookie_wp-wpml_current_language  $redirect {
   "example.com:UA:''" "1";
   "example.com:UA:'uk'" "0";
   "example.com:UA:'ru'" "0";
}
```

Then in *domain.conf* I just check use *$redirect* in conditional statement

```
if ($redirect) {
    rewrite ^https://example.com/uk break;
}
```

So, my question is: how to check the value of a cookie the right way in general, and how to check if cookie is not set (has empty value) in particular using *map* directive for *nginx*?

Comment: Make use of a script language?

Comment: Using Lua scripting is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration outlined below fits my needs

```
map $host $redirect_host {
    example.com 1;
    default 0;
}

map $geoip_country_code $redirect_country {
    UA 1;
    default 0;
}

map $cookie_wp-wpml_current_language $redirect_cookie {
    uk 0;
    ru 0;
    default 1;
}

map $redirect_host:$redirect_country:$redirect_cookie $make_redirect {
    1:1:1 1;
}
```

Then use *$make_redirect* variable that way in domain's configuration

```
if ($make_redirect) {
    rewrite ^https://example.com/uk break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the several `map` conditions to separate blocks:

```
map $host $redirect_host {
    example.com 1;
    default 0;
}

map $geoip_country $redirect_country {
    UA 1;
    default 0;
}

map $cookie_wp-wpml_current_language $redirect_cookie {
    uk 0;
    default 1;
}
```

Then check the conditions as follows:

```
if (${redirect_host}${redirect_country}${redirect_cookie} = 111) {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/uk/;
}
```

You need to check the defaults and conditions for each variable to match your purposes, this was just an illustration of the concept.

Comment: How can you combine several different variables into one?
I get 
```nginx: [emerg] unknown "redirect_host$redirect_country$redirect_cookie" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```
while testing your solution on my side.
Did you test it in practice?

Comment: I did not test it. I added now braces around the variable names, which should fix the issue.

Comment: Nope, error is the same, unfortunately.
But thanks for hint anyway.